# Is it possible to edit Windows 8 swipe actions?

Tags: windows-8, taskbar, gestures

I would like to edit edge swipes in Windows 8. Specifically, I want to swipe up to show the taskbar.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: No, currently there is no way to customize the gestures. What do you want to change?

Comment: Seems like he wants to adjust the "swipe up" action.

Answer (score 1):

Nope, probably not. Unless your touchscreen/touchpad driver has a setting for this, it's not possible. It's worth a look to see if they do support it though.

To look at your driver settings, go to `Control Panel > Mouse`. Your driver probably places an extra tab on the right of this dialog, allowing you to access its settings. Some drivers also place an icon in the system tray on the Desktop, so you might want to take a look there as well for settings.

Answer (score -2):

Theres is an app called "Microsoft Device Center" wich allows to custumize gestures and mouse gestures to a certain point. Maybe it fits your needs.

[32 bit Version](http://download.microsoft.com/download/8/F/5/8F5AE7C0-3ABF-442E-805A-A696F1992E66/DeviceCenterBeta_32bit_ENG_1.0.406.0.exe)

[64 bit Version](http://download.microsoft.com/download/8/F/5/8F5AE7C0-3ABF-442E-805A-A696F1992E66/DeviceCenterBeta_64bit_ENG_1.0.406.0.exe)

```
     "A new application that helps you make the most out of your Microsoft 
keyboard and mouse.

            Customize devices from an easy-to-learn Windows 8 interface.
            Create new shortcuts that make tedious tasks a breeze."
```

[Credits](https://www.microsoft.com/hardware/en-us/downloads/mouse-keyboard-center)

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but this only works with a Microsoft mouse/keyboard.